# PHP and Mysql not echoing my variable

Tags: php, mysql, echo, large-data, postal-code

Not sure if I have coded this incorrectly or if it is just because I have a very large database that I am trying to pull from.

I'm not receiving any errors but there is just nothing being displayed on the page. Is having a large database an issue which might prevent me from being able to find my result. I know that the postcode is within the database as I have found it in `PHPMYADMIN SQL` tab.

```
<?php

$location = $user['location'];

$postcode = DB::query("SELECT * FROM postcodes WHERE Postcode LIKE '%" . $location . "%'");

$longitude = $postcode['Longitude'];

echo $longitude;

?>
```

I'm getting the `$user['location']` from a query which is already loaded in and `echo`s on the page shows the postcode on the page already.

I'm very new to `PHP` and `MYSQL` so am trying to learn but when it isn't giving me any errors it makes it very hard to search for what I am looking for.

Thank you very much 
   - Jonny Dommett

EDIT - Table Schema

```
id          int(11)         NO      PRI     NULL    auto_increment  
Postcode    varchar(8)      NO              NULL        
Latitude    decimal(9,6)    NO              NULL        
Longitude   decimal(9,6)    NO              NULL
```

EDIT - PDO

```
    <?php
  class DB{

    private static function connect(){
      $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vapoural_wsc;charset=utf8','testing','testing123');
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      return $pdo;

    }
    public static function query($query, $params = array()){
      $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
      $statement->execute($params);


   if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
  $data = $statement-> fetchAll();
  return $data;
}

    }
  }

 ?>
```

EDIT - VAR DUMP

```
var_dump($postcode);
```

produced a result of

`array(0) { }`

EDIT - SQL WITHIN PHPMYADMIN

[image]

EDIT - The ISSUE = FIXED

The Issue was from within my database on where I had entered my data. Make sure to check your columns by doing VARDUMP to see what that results first.

Comment: You `echo` `$longitude` but you set `$logitude` without the 'n'. I guess the error displaying is not enabled in your `php.ini`, otherwise it would tell you.

Comment: @RonnieOosting It's result is NULL but the database has nothing set as NULL

Comment: @AnthonyB I didn't notice that I have changed it but it did not change anything. I'm not to sure I will have a look at the php.ini now.

Comment: Please update your question with the code without the typo, and provide us your table schema (column names). You've used `Logitude` in the array key too.

Comment: @AnthonyB I have added the table schema and changed the errors in the spelling.

Comment: Now could you provide us some more informations? A reproducible example would be great but there you are using `DB::query`, please write your code with a basic PDO/mysqli code in this example. A `var_dump($postcode)` would be useful too.

Comment: @AnthonyB What do you mean a reproducible Example? The var dump produced array(0) { }

Ok so that is not what I thought it would produce at all.

Comment: By _reproducible example_ I mean a code I can test on my machine to help you. So please write your code with PDO or mysqli in order to have no dependencies.

Comment: @AnthonyB I have now added my PDO class into the edit.

Comment: I've tested it, and it works on my machine. I think your error was the $longitude/$logitude, and now your query doesn't find anything because your `$location` does not match. Try to set a static `$location`.

Comment: Please add `try-catch` blocks inside your query and connect functions. This way you can catch if there's an error on your code, instead of looking at a blank page. Also put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your page so it will notify you if there's any error in it.

Comment: @AnthonyB What do you mean by add static $location sorry I'm very new to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was in because of your typo in the variables `$longitude/$logitude` and in the array key `Logitude`.

Here is a working code, tested on my machine.

```
<?php
class DB{
    private static function connect(){
      $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vapoural_wsc;charset=utf8','testing','testing123');
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      return $pdo;

    }
    public static function query($query, $params = array()){
      $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
      $statement->execute($params);
      if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
          $data = $statement-> fetchAll();
          return $data;
      }
    }
}


$location = '4200';
$query = "SELECT * FROM postcodes WHERE Postcode LIKE ?";
var_dump(DB::query($query, ['%'.$location.'%']));
```

Output :

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(8) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["Postcode"]=>
  string(5) "42000"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "42000"
  ["Latitude"]=>
  string(4) "2344"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "2344"
  ["Longitude"]=>
  string(4) "2334"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "2334"
  }
}
```

The output is an example of random datas that I've inserted in my database.

> **Important note** : this code use a prepared statement. You are using a variable in your query, so please use a prepared statement to avoid SQL injection.

In this code I've set `$location` to a static value to be sure the provided code works.

Comment: You can always do `"SELECT * FROM postcodes WHERE Postcode LIKE concat('%',?,'%')"` if you're using a db framework, that uses `%` for sthg else.

Comment: Thank you what was your result from the Var dump as mine still says array(0) { }.

Comment: @JonnyGinaDommett I've added an output example.

Comment: @AnthonyB I have just tested mine if I set `$location` to . `$location = $user['location']; `  the result is  ` array(0) { } `

but if I set it to `$location = "BN11 3HB";`

then I get what I want it to print out I have just checked the `$user['location'] ` and if I just echo that I get `"BN11 3HB"` it just doesn't work I am very confused now

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyB The Issue was my fault there was a space in the database where I had inserted the postcode and added an extra space god I feel like a fool.

Thank you very much tho.